# How to copy a table definition (including hierarchies & measures) from one Power BI Report to another report within Power BI Desktop

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, m

Is it possible to import or copy a table definition from one Power BI report to another report, within Power Bi Desktop.

So from one Power BI report copy the following to another report:

- Source query which defines the table (i.e column types, data source etc.)
- Any hierarchies defined within the table
- Any Measures attached to the table

The contained data isn't important rather its the definition I would like to transfer.

Hopefully, this is all done without basically manually recreating each part.
I would be happy if this as simple copying a M-Query/DAX script between report and running it.

I have tried using a Power Bi templates, but this only seem to be useful as starting point in creating a report as it always creates a new report. I am looking for some way to transfer definitions between already created reports.

Answer (score 2):

Until now (as far as I now) its just possible to copy everything what was done in the query designer to another report.

Go to `Edit Queries` click on your table on the left side, which you want to copy and go to `Home > Advanced Editor`. Copy the whole text.

Now in your other report add a blank query in your query designer, then go to the advanced editor and hit insert. If nothing changed (soure path, file name, etc...) you will have the same table with the applied steps as in the other report.

Comment: I'll be honest, I am not that good with the M-Query language. Can I create table hierarchies within the advanced editor?

Comment: Hmm I dont think so, but I am not sure

Comment: Powerquery is at the extract and transform stage. The query editor fully copies any dependencies. So if query2 references query1, it'll paste them both in one go. -- If by heirarchy, you mean the data model, then you can use `Tabular Editor`

Answer (score 0):

It's only a partial solution, but you can very easily copy/paste entire queries between reports.  It doesn't get measures and DAX columns, though.

Source report -> Query Editor -> Queries pane on left -> Right click source query -> Copy

Destination report -> Query Editor -> Queries pane -> Left click -> Paste